# How to import lodash in angular 13 application level?

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, angular13

I'm trying to import lodash in angular application level through main.ts like below.

```
//main.ts
import * as lodash from 'lodash';
declare global {
  const _: typeof lodash;
}
```

[image]

After adding above code, I can able to reference to the lodash and compiled successfully but in run time I was facing issue like below.

```
ERROR ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

am I missing anything here? please help, thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you adding the above code in your `main.ts` file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Andres2142 , I thought main.ts is the root file in bootstrapping process, so if I can declare the variable here we can access application level without re-import again and again.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't tried that myself, I can suggest installing `@types/lodash` so you have auto-completion, and then just import lodash in every file you need.

Comment: I did not try this approach, but I think it should work. Try something like `(window as any)['_'] = lodash` in you `main.ts`. With `declare` you added type of global `_` everywhere, and with that `window` property assignment you add actual value to be used in any context.

Comment: Just tried that approach with [linq](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq), seems to work fine. One note, tho: if you're going to use Angular Universal, you might want to use `globalThis` instead of `window`.

Comment: Thanks @alx , It is working after adding `(window as any)['_'] = lodash` Or `(globalThis as any)['_'] = lodash`

Comment: Let me write it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way to do that:

```js
//main.ts
import * as lodash from 'lodash';

// This makes `_` available globally as a TS type:
declare global {
  const _: typeof lodash;
}

// And this makes `_` available globally as a JS object:
(window as any)['_'] = lodash;

// Or use this in case browser is not the only target platform:
(globalThis as any)['_'] = lodash;
```

Of course, this file should be imported before everything else.